# How can I get a touch-friendlier version of GMail on Opera Mobile?

Tags: gmail

- The IMAP client in Symbian doesn't let me archive
- The standard web interface has been retired and I'm stuck with the mobile view with teeny links and painful, keypad based navigation
- The gmail symbian app is <s>deprecated if not wholesale retired</s> obsolescent

Is there another version of GMail I can use that is touchscreen friendlier?

Comment: m.gmail.com doesn't work for you?

Comment: That's the mobile view with teeny little links and painful, keypad based navigation.

Comment: Ah. Nevermind, then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visit the HTML only (no AJAX) version of GMail - https://mail.google.com/mail/h/

That'll give you far more functionality than the usual mobile format.

Comment: Wow, I thought it had been retired :)

Answer (score 0):

Both my iPhone and iPad redirect to: `https://mail.google.com/mail/mu/#tl/Inbox` when going to `http://gmail.com`.

You might want to give that URL a try.

If that doesn't work, you could try spoofing your user agent to appear to the website as an iPhone (although some things might break).

Comment: I get a 404 for that address.

Comment: +1 badp you should un-downvote these two answers, they work for us, but for some reason, they're being blocked for you, and it seems, only you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link;

http://mail.google.com/mail/x/gdlakb-/gp/

Info taken from here;

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/10/gmail-modes.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get 404 here too :(

Comment: The fact that you are getting 404 errors for all solutions offered makes me think you have connection problems rather then there being a problem with the links given.